# How to apply spans to the whole Spannable string

Tags: android, kotlin

Everywhere I see only these ways:

```
text[0..3] = AlignmentSpan.Standard(Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_OPPOSITE)
```

or using setSpan, but there I must only use some limits(start and end indexes).

Then I tried this:

```
text[text.indices] = AlignmentSpan.Standard(Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_OPPOSITE)
```

It works, but it excludes the last character.

How to apply spans to the whole Spannable string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `setSpan` and define the first and last index.

```
val span = AlignmentSpan.Standard(Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_OPPOSITE)
text.setSpan(span, 0, text.length, 0)
```

and since `AlignmentSpan` is a `ParagraphStyle` it must be applied to the whole block of text (which can be split by the newline character `\n`).

Answer (score 0):

i guss you are looking for this
because they must be stored in loop to apply multiple properties in many elements

```kotlin
val list = ArrayOf(text1,text2,text3)// <- store your all text here
list.forEach{
    it = AlignmentSpan.Standard(Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_OPPOSITE)
}
```

or

```kotlin
val list = ArrayOf(text1,text2,text3)// <- store your all text here
for(element in list){
    element = AlignmentSpan.Standard(Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_OPPOSITE)
}
```

or

```kotlin
(0..(list.length - 1)).forEach{
    list[it] = AlignmentSpan.Standard(Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_OPPOSITE)
}
```

or

```kotlin
text.forEach{
    it = AlignmentSpan.Standard(Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_OPPOSITE)//this one applied to every char
}
```

Comment: What variable type does have your text1(text2, etc.)?

Comment: if it is many different text view you can use the above method or if it it is single string you can use ```toList()``` or ```split("")``` to convert it to array which works too @Viktor